# Visual Studio 2013 Bad Intellisense

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013 and am having issues in an MVC project.  Specifically the intellisense is messed up and says there are errors when there are not.

[image]

The project still builds however, and works fine. Has anyone had this problem and been able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear the project (Menu > Build > Clear 'MyProject') and then Rebuild the project. Note that for me clearing the solution does not work, must clear the project.

For me, VS2013 seems to 'forget it knows MVC'! All my MVC references break, all my @Url and @Html stuff breaks. The fix is to clear the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem. For me it was broken references that didn't read as broken. If you look at the ones that are saying they are broken, then delete and recreate the references you will likely be able to fix the problem.